# Unable to get Location Update From Mobile App when the app is minimized and kept for 10 minutes

Tags: android, kotlin

We are building a Mobile App where in we need extract GPS Location of the Mobile so that we can upload to our Server every 15 seconds.

Although we are able to get continuous GPS Location update When the App is in the foreground. But when the app is minimized for 10 minutes, Location is coming up as null.

Can anyone know how to get this location uninterrupted which works kind of in all major Mobiles ?

We tried several options, but still GPS location will be null after 10 minutes.

Comment: Are you using a foreground service? Is the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission provided?

Comment: We are already doing this. Still it doesnt work in all the mobile like Oppo Vivo, Samsung etc. Any other suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) in order to send continuous location updates.

This way, even if the application is in the background it will still be able to perform async operations such as location updates.

Practically, you can use [LifeCycleService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleService) for your service class and add your api call in   "onStartCommend"

Comment: We are already doing using Foreground Service. Still in Several mobiles like Oppo, Vivo, Samsung, location comes as null sometimes after 10 minutes, and in some devices after 30 min. Any other thoughts anyone

Comment: We even tried to send an FCM notification to trigger it again (like start the service upon receiving this notification). Still this doesn't work in all mobiles. Appreciate your help. Thx